# Open wpf menu upwards

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am trying to put a menu in the statusbar that is at the bottom of a custom user control.

When I click on the menu, it opens downwards, as usually happens with menus, with the result that the menu exits from the usercontrol.

How can I force the menu to open above the statusbar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To open a context menu upwards, you must set the Placement property to `Top`:

`ContextMenu.Placement = System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.PlacementMode.Top;`

Comment: can I do this in xaml?

Comment: sure, just specify it in the context menu tag as follows: `<ContextMenu Placement="Top"`>

Comment: Some info on how Popups (and ContextMenus) placement works in WPF: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/popup-placement-behavior?view=netcore-3.1